# Variable columns in tabular

Tags: tables

I am working on a table that some rows have three columns and some others only two.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ | m{5em} | m{1.5cm}| m{1.5cm} | } 
          \hline
           & $ \frac{\partial^2_f}{\partial^2_x} > 0 $ & $ \frac{\partial^2_f}{\partial^2_x} < 0 $  \\ 
          \hline
          $\bigl|H| > 0$ & mínim & màxim \\ 
          \hline
          $\bigl|H| < 0$ & punt de sella \\ 
          \hline
          $\bigl|H| = 0 $ & No ho podem dir \\ 
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

I want :

```
$\bigl|H| < 0$ & punt de sella \\
```

and

```
$\bigl|H| = 0 $ & No ho podem dir \\
```

to become one single column centered under the two previous.

How can I achieve that?
[image: Render of my table]

Comment: use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{No ho podem dir}`

Comment: as your image shows, `\bigl|H|` makes a big | on the left and normal | on the right which seems weird?  I would not use big at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two examples:

- with `tabular`, and
- with `tabularray` and `derivative` packages

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{5em} | m{2cm}| m{2cm} | }
      \hline
              & $ \frac{\partial^2_f}{\partial^2_x} > 0 $
                        & $ \frac{\partial^2_f}{\partial^2_x} < 0 $  \\
\hline
$\abs{H} > 0$ & mínim   & màxim \\
\hline
$\abs{H} < 0$ & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{punt de sella}       \\
\hline
$\abs{H} = 0$ &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{No ho podem dir}    \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

with \verb+tblr+ of \verb+tabularrray+ and \verb+derivative+ package:

\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[mode=math, wd=5em]
                       *{2}{Q[c, wd=2cm]}},
                 row{1} = {mode=dmath}
                 }
                &  \pdv[order=2]{f}{x} > 0
                    & \pdv[order=2]{f}{x} < 0   \\
\abs{H} > 0 & mínim & màxim \\
\abs{H} < 0 & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  punt de sella   \\
\abs{H} = 0 & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  No ho podem dir \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]